# Is it possible to access\collect log.html report during execution of robot framework script?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I want to collect the each test case result from log.html during the execution of script.

Answer (score 1):

The log.html is generated once all tests are finished, so during execution you cannot access it.

You can use the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) of the framework to get test case data during execution. The Listener Version 2 defines the `end_test` method which will be called every time when a test case ends.

It will be called with to parameters: `name` and `attributes`.

> Contents of the attribute dictionary:
>
> - id: Same as in start_test.
> - longname: Same as in start_test.
> - doc: Same as in start_test.
> - tags: Same as in start_test.
> - critical: Same as in start_test.
> - template: Same as in start_test.
> - starttime: Same as in start_test.
> - endtime: Test execution execution end time.
> - elapsedtime: Total execution time in milliseconds as an integer
> - status: Test status as string PASS or FAIL.
> - message: Status message. Normally an error message or an empty string.

I guess the `status` information is what you need. Here is an example from the user guide:

```
"""Listener that stops execution if a test fails."""

ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

def end_test(name, attrs):
    if attrs['status'] == 'FAIL':
        print('Test "%s" failed: %s' % (name, attrs['message']))
        raw_input('Press enter to continue.')
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a report in html format with pass\fail result so I can link the data to some other thread

Comment: @Pdk Well, as I said you cannot do that only az the end of the execution. By the way the listener interface defines a method which will be called when the log.html file is ready, but again it will be invoked after all tests have been finished.